# Python Script to return records added in last 1 hour in MongoDB collection

Tags: python, mongodb

Above Script is giving error at gt as Invalid Syntax; could someone help me in this. I was trying to retrieve records inserted in last 1hour.

````
import pymongo
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from pymongo import MongoClient
# establish connectivity to Mongodb via ssl using pymongo module
#args = sys.argv

host = 'mongo-db-prd'
uname = 'superuser'
passwrd = 'Hayyo'
#print (args)
port = "27017"
print(uname)
print(passwrd)
uri = 'mongodb://' + uname + ":" + passwrd + "@" + host + ":" + port + '/?authSource=admin'

client = MongoClient(uri, ssl=True, ssl_ca_certs='./files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem')
# This will create hl7feeds docdb
print("connected client")
db = client.feeds  # This command will create a DB
print(client.list_database_names()) # This command will print list of DBs
print(client.list_database_names()) # This command will print list of DBs
mycol = db[ "feeds_100"]  # This command will create a collection in DB
docins=mycol.insert_one({"name" : "test"})  # This will insert a document in collection
dblist = client.list_database_names()
print(client.list_database_names())

# Lets create collections on docdb for all tenants
tlist1 = ["feeds_104","feeds_105","feeds_106"]

for each_val in tlist1:
   print (each_val)
   countvalue = db.getCollection('each_val').find({"row_created_date":{"$gt":datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)}}).count();
   print (countvalue)```
````

Comment: The date expression is wrong, try `new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1*60*60 * 1000)` or `datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)` (I never worked with python)

Comment: Above query is giving Zero Value, not sure what went wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `javascript` code inside `python`:

```
countvalue = db.getCollection('each_val').find({"row_created_date":{"$gt":new date(date.now() - 1*60*60 * 1000)}}).count();
```

Correct it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

...

countvalue = db.getCollection('each_val').find({"row_created_date":{"$gt":datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)}}).count();
```

Also, formatted your code, for better understanding:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from pymongo import MongoClient

# establish connectivity to Mongodb via ssl using pymongo module
# args = sys.argv

host = "mongo-db-prd"
uname = "superuser"
passwrd = "Hayyo"
# print (args)
port = "27017"
print(uname)
print(passwrd)
uri = (
    "mongodb://" + uname + ":" + passwrd + "@" + host + ":" + port + "/?authSource=admin"
)

client = MongoClient(uri, ssl=True, ssl_ca_certs="./files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
# This will create hl7feeds docdb
print("connected client")
db = client.feeds  # This command will create a DB
print(client.list_database_names())  # This command will print list of DBs
mycol = db["feeds_100"]  # This command will create a collection in DB
docins = mycol.insert_one({"name": "test"})  # This will insert a document in collection
dblist = client.list_database_names()
print(client.list_database_names())

# Lets create collections on docdb for all tenants
tlist1 = ["feeds_104", "feeds_105", "feeds_106"]

for each_val in tlist1:
    print(each_val)
    countvalue = (
        db.getCollection("each_val")
        .find({"row_created_date": {"$gt": datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)}})
        .count()
    )
    print(countvalue)
```

P.S. please look at [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to better format your `uri`

Comment: The above python script is running fine, but its giving value as 0 for last 1 hour updated records; Not sure what went wrong in above script; if I run query manually on mongodb its showing correct number